# backbone collection. fetch() not rendering the view in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

i am trying to learn backbone.js ( Backbone.js 1.0.0) this is  my sample html page where  iam using  collection. fetch()  method to get the collection,and it is displayed using view .i am getting result in 
google chrome,but nothing is displayed in  mozilla. i don't know the exact reason.

while i refere to backone site http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

it is qouted that :

Note that fetch should not be used to populate collections on page load — all models needed at load time should already be bootstrapped in to place. fetch is intended for lazily-loading models for interfaces that are not needed immediately: for example, documents with collections of notes that may be toggled open and closed.

is this is related with my issue?

this is my sample html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Backbone Application</title>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="js/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<div class="list"></div>

<script id="personTemplate" type="text/template">
<td>  <strong><%= name %></strong></td>
 <td>(<%= age %>) </td>
<td> <%= occupation %> </td>  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Person Model
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Guest User',
        age: 30,
        occupation: 'worker'
    }
});
// A List of People
var PeopleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    initialize: function(){
        alert("intialise")
    },
    url:'/RestFul/rest/members/info',

});
// View for all people
var PeopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'table',
    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(person){
            var personView = new PersonView({ model: person });
            this.$el.append(personView.render().el); // calling render method manually..
        }, this);
        return this; // returning this for chaining..
    }
});
// The View for a Person
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: _.template($('#personTemplate').html()),
       //////////   initialize function is gone from there. So we need to call render method manually now..

    render: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;  // returning this from render method..
    }
});
var peopleCollection = new PeopleCollection();
//peopleCollection.fetch();
peopleCollection.fetch({ success: function () { console.log("collection fetched");  } });
//peopleCollection.fetch({context:collection}).done(function() {
    //  console.log(this.length)
//  })
//console.log(peopleCollection.toJSON())
alert(JSON.stringify(peopleCollection));
var peopleView = new PeopleView({ collection: peopleCollection });
$(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el);   // adding people view in DOM
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
var fetching = peopleCollection.fetch({ success: function () { console.log("collection fetched");  } });

$.when(fetching).done(function(){
    var peopleView = new PeopleView({ collection: peopleCollection });
    $(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el);   // adding people view in DOM
});
```

Comment: Using `$.when` is pointless, `fetching` is already a jqXHR object: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Comment: @DavidSulc Sulc its works now,but i have one more doubt,why this is not rendered in mozilla for my code  ,i get the response correctly  in google chrome

Comment: LIkely becasue they work differently: Mozilla get to the view display code sooner, or takes longer to fetch the collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fetching = peopleCollection.fetch({ success: function () { 
             var peopleView = new PeopleView({ collection: peopleCollection });
             $(document.body).append(peopleView.render().el);
 } });
```

I think we can call the view render inside the success callback